# How to convert UTF-8 <-> UTF16 portable

Tags: c++, utf-8, portability, utf-16

is there a simple, portable way (win32, linux at least) to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 and back? Preferably using boost.

Thx for your help,
Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) and [icu](http://icu-project.org/) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is for academic purposes, you can convert to UTF-32 and then to UTF-8 or UTF-16. Unicode.org has a convenient [PDF](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/ch03.pdf) that contains a table of bit distributions for UTF-32, UTF-16, and UTF-8.