# string conversion between UTF-8 representation and unicode representation

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm

How to design an algorithm to convert a UTF-8 string to a unicode string?

Comment: What's a unicode string? You mean a sequence of Unicode code points?

Comment: UTF-8 *is* Unicode.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If this is an interview question, then the questioner probably thinks that "unicode string" and "wide character string" mean the same thing. You can opt to spend interview time educating them, or you clarify whether that's what they mean and move on to the bit where you show them you can write code ;-)

Comment: UTF-8 is one of 'unicode representations'. What is the other representation then?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287212/how-to-convert-utf-8-utf16-portable/2287344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters are right. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode and rephrase question.

UTF-8 is a ''represenation'' of unicode. You probably want to recode to some other interpretation, maybe Java Strings or Microsoft Visual C++ multibyte chracter strings...